# 2 Divs with fixed position, one gets pushed away as the other gets shown

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, css-position

I programm a website with a footer, which is fixed at the bottom of the site. I show a div element (#container) on a mouseover event which is also fixed, right above the footer. In chrome it works perfectly when the div shows up (display:none to display:inline). In IE the footer gets pushed down EVERY SINGLE TIME and i have no idea why :'-( CSS looks like this:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed !important; 

    /*position: absolute;*/
    height: 20px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    text-align: left;   
    z-index: 3;
}

 #container{
    position: fixed;
    height: 550px;
    bottom: 30px;
    right:0;
    width: 550px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
    background: url(images/pau1_500g.png) no-repeat center center ;
    border: black 2px solid;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    background-size: 55%;
    z-index:2;
}
```

The first line NO LONGER looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9">
```

thanks in advance and comment if i should provide more code/info!

EDIT:EDIT:
HTML with JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>*****</title>
<link href="myCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var req;
        var params;
        var posx;
        var posy;
        var testTime;
        var outTime;
    function realTest(id){
        params = "pauid="+id+"&nom=true&extreme=true";
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("get","azubi/highchartAJAX.php?"+params,true);
        req.send(null);
        req.onreadystatechange = evaluate;
    }

    function test(id){
            clearTimeout(testTime);
            testTime = setTimeout("realTest("+id+")",3000);
        }

    function evaluate(){
        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
            var se = document.createElement('script');
            se.type = "text/javascript";
            se.text = req.responseText;
            se.id = "testing";
            var toDel = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
            for(i = 0; i < toDel.length; i++){
                if(toDel[i].id=="testing"){
                    toDel[i].parentNode.removeChild(toDel[i]);
                }
            }
            document.body.appendChild(se);
        }
        var toShow = document.getElementById("container");
        toShow.style.display = "inline";
    }
</script> 
</head>
<body >
<div id="container"> </div>

<tr onmouseover='test($row[56])' onmouseout='out(this)'>
<div id="footer">
***
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you in IE 7 compatibility mode ? `<meta>` tags  must be in `<head>` section

Comment: You not a fan of HTML5  :)   Your doctype just wants html and like @alexis say's drop the meta..

Comment: sadly, dropping the <meta> line did not work... even more sadly is, that i have to fix it becaus some users use ie...

Comment: Can you post a js fiddle or a code snippet for your currently working code?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen done

Comment: Can you post the html as well?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen not everything... You want to see the parts where i declare onmouseover and the container?

Comment: ya that will be fine

Comment: What's with the random unclosed `tr` tag? `tr` tags must be within a table, thead or tbody and closed

Comment: @Pete the tag is closed and inside a table, i just cant publish everything. GraveyardQueen wanted to see where i declare the onmouseover event.

Comment: I know your html is a cut down version but you appear to have a floating tr without a containing table and without a closing tag or any td elements in it... Also your script seems to be doing httprequests to content that we don't have access to (in that we don't know what server it is on). Create a proper cut down version of your page (really, actually create the page, not just cut out bits when you copy and paste here) that demonstrates your problem and that we can run ourselves and you are more likely to get a positive response. You may also while trimming it down find the problem yourself.

Comment: @Chris thanks for the tip i will do so

Comment: what exactly do you want?do you want the footer to be fixed at the bottom and the div to be alongside the table?

Comment: have you tried changing the display to block instead of inline?

Comment: footer fixed on the bottom - div exactly above it and showing on mouseover. at the moment it pushs down the footer (only in ie). @Chris i tried to make a "sandbox" and reproduce the behavior, but there it works... Pete i tried, nothing changed.

Comment: position fixed doiesn't work properly in ie7 so if you are running ie7 emulation then it won't work

Comment: @bloodscript: This is exactly why you need to make a minimum reproduction. Your sandbox didn't show the problem so now you have narrowed down the problem to something still in the original page but not in the new page. My approach is generally to take the original page and keep removing bits that I think are not relevant one at a time, refreshing the page and retesting each time I do. At some point the bug will stop occurring and you know that the last chunk you deleted was a contributing factor. Leave that in and remove other bits. Sooner or later you'll get to the stage where... (continued)

Comment: ...everything left in the page needs to be there for the bug to occur. At this point you either have a much simpler problem that you can solve or if not a complete recreation of the problem that you can hand to others (if you still have sensitive text in there that couldn't be removed replace it with Lorem Ipsum - if that stops the problem from happening then you're going to have to share the text).

Comment: Also Pete has made me realise you never specified what version of internet explorer you are having problems on. I assume IE11 since that is the only officially supported versions these days. If it is older versions of IE then you should push hard to not have to support them. If Microsoft doesn't support older versions of IE any more then you shouldn't have to either. And your users should upgrade to a supported version or they are leaving themselves open to potential security risks and such like.

Comment: @Chris thanks for your effort, i am reproducing more and more, til i find the problem or the site is "rebuild" and working. i am using ie 11, so do my users. i thank you a lot for your tips, now i first try to reproduce the error step by step so i find it. can anyone close the question? right now i feel kind of embaressed not to know how i can solve problems :D

Comment: If you want the question gone you should be able to delete it yourself. No need to be embarrassed about things though. People have problems and hopefully you have got some of the help you need from asking here.

Comment: @Chris Okay i found the point it stopped working: when you have a horizontal scrollbar and then show the div. No problem for chrome, but for ie. sadly i need the horizontal scrollbar... anyone got an idea how to prevent the footer from hiding behind the scrollbar?

Comment: @bloodscript: Now you have a more focussed question you are probably best off asking a new question specifically for that point now you can hopefully put in a short complete example of your problem. Asking for help in comments here for an updated question is not likely to have a very big audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Thank You All!

I did it whit two simple changes:

1. Get rid of the meta Tag
2. Give body element the property height:100%;

So easy! Problem was the horizontal scrollbar which pushed in front of the footer because... no one knows.

Special Thanks to Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code and check in both the browsers ,and it is displaying the same for both,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>*****</title>
<style>
#footer {
    position: fixed !important; 
    /*position: absolute;*/
    height: 20px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    text-align: left;   
    z-index: 3;
}

 #container{
    position: fixed;
    height: 550px;
    bottom: 30px;
    right:0;
    width: 550px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
    background: url(images/pau1_500g.png) no-repeat center center ;
    border: black 2px solid;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    background-size: 55%;
    z-index:2;
}
</style>
<link href="myCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var req;
        var params;
        var posx;
        var posy;
        var testTime;
        var outTime;
    function realTest(id){
        params = "pauid="+id+"&nom=true&extreme=true";
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("get","azubi/highchartAJAX.php?"+params,true);
        req.send(null);
        req.onreadystatechange = evaluate;
    }

    function test(id){
            clearTimeout(testTime);
            testTime = setTimeout("realTest("+id+")",3000);
        }

    function evaluate(){
        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
            var se = document.createElement('script');
            se.type = "text/javascript";
            se.text = req.responseText;
            se.id = "testing";
            var toDel = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
            for(i = 0; i < toDel.length; i++){
                if(toDel[i].id=="testing"){
                    toDel[i].parentNode.removeChild(toDel[i]);
                }
            }
            document.body.appendChild(se);
        }
        var toShow = document.getElementById("container");
        toShow.style.display = "inline";
    }
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"> 
sdfdsf
</div>
<table style="height:50%">
<tr onmouseover='test(56)'>
<td>
sdfsdfsdf
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="footer">
***
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have not made any changes to the existing code and it seems to be displaying properly